# Using sidewaystable environment with footnotetext

Tags: tables, numbering, footnotes, rotating

My new problem is this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}[h!]
      \centering
       \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
       \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}||p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
         \hline
           EJ       & \textbf{471}   & \textbf{575}    & \textbf{671}  & \textbf{675}    \\
         \hline
           a        & 12  & dfg   & fg\footnotemark[1] &  ffd  \\ 
         \hline
           a        & 42  & fdg   & s\footnotemark[2] &  sdf  \\ 
         \hline           
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{Bla bla bla bla bla.}
      \label{A7660C1}
      \footnotetext[1]{ bla}
      \footnotetext[2]{ bla bla}
    \end{sidewaystable} 
\end{document}
```

[image: table]

I don't understand why, in the table are footnote references (`\footnotemark`) as numbers -> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lCMe.png) and [2], but footnote text are referenced as letters -> [a] and [b] (`\footnotetext`). This problem is seen in the attached pdf document. I am running Miktex 2.9 (XeLaTeX).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `\footnotemark`. `\footnote` will work fine as you are in a minipage.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}[h!]
    %\renewcommand\thempfootnote{\arabic{mpfootnote}}%if you want arabic numbers
      \centering
       \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
       \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}||p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
         \hline
           EJ       & \textbf{471}   & \textbf{575}    & \textbf{671}  & \textbf{675}    \\
         \hline
           a        & 12  & dfg   & fg\footnote{bla} &  ffd  \\
         \hline
           a        & 42  & fdg   & s\footnote{blablab}&  sdf  \\
         \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{Bla bla bla bla bla.}
      \label{A7660C1}

    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a really quick answer. Thank you very much. Other option is using tablefootnote package. This LATEX package provides the command \tablefootnote to be used in
a table or sidewaystable environment, where \footnote will not work and
when using \footnotemark and \footnotetext and adjusting the counters
(including Hfootnote) manually is either too much work or would not even
work (sidewaystable).